# What should I do if my question body exceed 30000 characters?

Tags: discussion, character-limit

I need to provide a log which might be helpful for root cause identifying. However, the log exceed 30000 characters that I can't add it into my question.

Is there anyway for workaround?

--EDIT--

I was asked for the verbose log, which I can hardly see any clues of it. So I don't know which part of the log should be taken out.

Then I came here to see if there is a website or somewhere that I can share this hull log if someone might interest.

But you guys are right, maybe I'd better get back to my problem and do more investigation before asking.

Comment: There's no way that entire log is going to be relevant to your question, and there's certainly no way someone here is actually going to look through the *entire* thing. 30,000 characters is a *lot* of characters. Is it not possible to summarize it by extracting just a section, or finding the relevant parts of it?

Comment: What log are you posting? 30K characters is a LOT for *anyone* to scroll through. Are all 30K necessary? Perhaps limit it?

Comment: You want answers to your question, right? Can you expect someone going to read your 30K log to answer your question? What you should do **is to help others answer your question**.  Posting 30K log does the exact opposite.. Ideally, a question should warrant an answer..

Comment: Here's a workaround: **post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).** What were you thinking?!

Comment: If you really think it's necessary to attach the whole file you can host it somewhere and post a link.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No one wants to read 30k+ characters of logfile.

The best solution is to put more time into narrowing down where the problem is and then posting only the relevant portion of the logfile.